# maven copy plugin for spring-boot

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I have created a Spring Boot application where I have few Javascript & Html files in the path src/main/resources/public/app.

My project folder structure is :

```
/project
 -/src/main
 -- /java
 -- / resources
 --- /application.properties
 --- /public
  ---- /app
  ----- /index.html
  ----- /bower-components
  ----- /scripts
  ----- /views/**.html
  ----- /images
  ----- /styles
  ----/dist
  -----/index.html
  -----/vendor.ZXASF.js
  -----/scripts.QASD.js
```

When I run the Javascript minification task, I generate a dist [distribution] folder as shown above. Now my requirement is, I want to tell maven which folder to include in the JAR file when `mvn clean install` is run. If I run in "DEBUG" mode, the folder `src/main/resources/app` folder needs to included in the JAR file. When I run in "DEPLOY" mode, the `src/main/resources/dist` folder needs to be included. Please note, the path of these folders in the JAR file should be as per the project folder structure. I tried with several options but no luck till now. My `pm.xml` is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>spring-boot-demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-boot-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>demo.SpringBootDemoApplication</start-class>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Thanks

Comment: You might take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754216/maven-deploy-additional-jar-file

Comment: That being said, do you plan on having non-java developers working on this app? You might consider moving the client /app outside of the java /src and into its own /client.  We use this setup for client side work which allows frontend devs that do not know java to have a Grunt workflow.